# Encoding variables using Postman

Tags: json, encoding, postman

Is it possible to encode the variables using Postman itself?

Ex :

```
{
  "UserName": "Admin0011@test.com",
  "Password": "test@123",
  "ConfirmPassword": "test@123",
  "Role": "SuperAdmin"
}
```

Is it possible to encode the password field using Postman itself and send it to the server? I am passing the above JSON data inside the body/header section.

Is it possible to do something like this inside Postman

```
base64UrlEncode(Password)
```

Comment: what do you mean encode?

Comment: @Beginner I modified the question . Please have a look

Comment: nope it's not possible in postman

Comment: I think it may be possible with Postman `Pre-request Scripts`. I'm not sure

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is how I handle key/secret encoding for connecting to appigee ouath

```
let keys = pm.environment.get("key") + ":" + pm.environment.get("secret");
let encodedKeys = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys));

pm.environment.set("encodedKeys", encodedKeys);
```

Using just stringify as proposed by the currently accepted answer I got an odd error stating r.clamp is not a function. To fix that I had to parse the keys first.

Comment: Agree, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was having the same problem with `e.clamp` is not a function.

Comment: This answer worked like a charm in pre-request script:
let keys = pm.environment.get("apiUsername") + ":" + pm.environment.get("apiKey");
let encodedKeys = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys));

Then setting the header "Authorization": 'Basic ' + encodedKeys,

Comment: I was using global variables but had no environment setup in postman so had to use pm.globals.get("key") instead of pm.environment.get("key")

Answer (score 20):

It's possible using [Postman Pre-request Scripts](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts) and [Postman Environment Variables](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables) .

First step is to set up the variables you want to encode.

Next, write a script. Postman has CryptoJs built-in, which you can use to encode strings. Here's a sample script to Base64 encode a string and set an environment variable to the encoded value:

```
var plainText = pm.environment.get('plainTextString');
var encoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(plainText);

console.log(`Encoded value: ${encoded}`) //if you want to see the value in the console
pm.environment.set("myEncodedRequestVariable", encoded);
```

Finally, use your encoded variables in the request body (or header) with this syntax:

```
{{myEncodedRequestVariable}}
```

Comment: I had issues getting CryptoJS to encode a string using the above sample code. The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524452/base64-encoder-via-crypto-js helped me figure out to turn my string into a Utf8 something or other first using ```CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(string);``` first and then pass that into the Base64.stringify.

Comment: DOWNVOTE because THIS IS NOT ENCRYPTION and as a result this answer could lead folks to make the dangerous and incorrect assumption that encoding == encryption.

Comment: @P.Roe The question is not about ENCRYPTION.

Comment: @MichaelSync using "encrypted" variable name may confuse user. You are not doing security encryption with base64... That P. Roe want to say.

Comment: Good point that that encoding != encryption in relation to the variable names. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Change request body in pre-request script](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808) you cannot change request body in postman unless you use variables.

If looking to Base64 encode/decode.

Easiest way is use JavaScript methods [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa), [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)

Here are the steps taking below JSON as your request

```
{
  "UserName": "Admin0011@test.com",
  "Password": "{{base64EncodedPassword}}",
  "ConfirmPassword": "{{base64EncodedPassword}}",
  "Role": "SuperAdmin"
}
```

1. Define first [environment variable](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/) in your postman environment called password (assuming you looking to encrypt password only). Make sure you set your unencrypted password value.
2. Define second environment variable called `base64EncodedPassword`. Leave its value blank.
3. You can then use following code in [Postman Pre-request script](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts/) tab.

```
pm.environment.set("base64EncodedPassword", btoa(pm.environment.get("password")));
```

Comment: btoa has a different purpose. Here the question is about url encoding which encodeURIComponent() does in javascipt

Comment: Finally, mutation of request body was added a couple of years later :) Here's a very valuable comment briefly demonstrating exactly what I was here for: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808#issuecomment-826838064